# What is the fastest way to iterate through a list of yfinance tickers?

Tags: python, data-science, finance, yfinance

Im using the python yfinance yahoo API for stock data retrieval. Right now im getting the peg ratio, which is an indicator of a company price related to its growth and earnings. I have a csv downloaded from here: https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener.
It has exactly 8000 stocks.

What I do is get the symbol list, and iterate it to access to the yahoo ticker. Then I get a use the ticker.info method which returns a dictionary. I iterate this process through the 8000 symbols. It goes at a speed of 6 symbols per minute, which is not viable. Is there a faster way with another API or another structure? I dont care about the API as long as I can get basic info as the growth, earnings, EPS and those things.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf


data = pd.read_csv("data/stock_list.csv")
symbols = data['Symbol']
for symbol in symbols:
    stock = yf.Ticker(symbol)
    try:
        if stock.info['pegRatio']:
            print(stock.info['shortName'] + " : " + str(stock.info['pegRatio']))
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: It seems that the pegRatio is not a direct lookup as you might have hoped. stock.info['pegRatio'] is where the time is being consumed. You might want to look at the Ticker class to see what it's doing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that when certain data are needed from the Ticker.info attribute, HTTP requests are made to acquire them. Multithreading will help to improve matters. Try this:-

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import concurrent.futures

data = pd.read_csv('data/stock_list.csv')

def getPR(symbol):
    sn = None
    pr = None
    try:
        stock = yf.Ticker(symbol)
        pr = stock.info['pegRatio']
        sn = stock.info['shortName']
    except Exception:
        pass
    return (sn, pr)


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(getPR, sym): sym for sym in data['Symbol']}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        sn, pr = future.result()
        if sn:
            print(f'{sn} : {pr}')
```

Comment: Thats crazy thanks! It's the first time I use mulithreading, will definitely investigate more about it.